# How to test restoring an in development iOS app from an iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, icloud

I need to do some testing with how my app behaves after the device has been restored from a backup.  Ideally I'd like to test my app after restoring from both a local iTunes backup and an iCloud backup.  An issue I'm having is that when I restore my device from iCloud it fails to restore my app because (I believe) iOS tries to download my app from the app store and since I haven't yet submitted my app, it is not present.  An alert appears on the device saying that some apps couldn't be restored and I should sync with iTunes to get them.  When I put my app in iTunes and sync (as the alert suggests), I don't get any backed up data for the app, it's like my app is being installed from fresh.

Restoring from a local iTunes backup works perfectly with my app, so I'm inclined to think that this issue with it failing when restoring from iCloud is a result of me restoring an in development app and not a bug on my end.  However, I'm not 100% certain.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Is it possible to test restoring an in development iOS app from an iCloud backup?

Answer (score -3):

I don't really think that's something you need to worry about testing as there isn't really anything you could do about it anyway; it'd be all Apple's fault if something did go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I pretty much agree that any problems found would probably be Apple's and not mine.  However, I like to push it as much as I can with testing.  I'm still hopeful there is a way for me to make this work.

Comment: This answer is not correct. iOS allows developers to specify the flag isExcludedFromBackup when storing things in disk, meaning developers can impact how their apps are backed up - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcevalues/1780002-isexcludedfrombackup

This also impacts third-party libraries like Realm which abstract disk storage. So it is definitely within a developer's ability to change how their apps are backed up, and there should be decent testing mechanisms for this.

Though this question was asked many years ago, so this may be something new.